# Removing black local video frame in iOS

Tags: video, webrtc, local, simplewebrtc

I am developing video conferencing apps using Apache Cordova, simplewebrtc, and cordova-plugin-iosrtc.

After an iOS user stopped the local video, there's a black video frame. How to remove it? It didnt happen in android and i've tried .hide, display and visibility but didnt worked out. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Did you try.. When user pressed the stop button your code will take a screenshot of video, then position that grab over video area so the area is finally not just an empty black box? Google if any of this is possible (HTML5 tutorials on video grabbing & positioning result image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by refreshing the video, cordova.plugins.iosrtc.refreshVideos(). Thank you.